# Getting reflectance from Sentinel2 L2A images

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, reflectance

I want to get surface reflectance at some points on GEE for Sentinel2 L2A images. I know that I can use inspector to get band values at each point. I read that these values are Digital Numbers and need to divide them by 10000 to get reflectance and it should be between 0 and 1. I just wanted to be sure if this procedure is right. And is it necessary to apply `.divide(10000)` to get the reflectance values or I can alternatively divide each band values manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. If you have any doubt please read the **Sentinel-2 L2A Product Format Specification document**: https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/685211/Sentinel-2-MSI-L2A-Product-Format-Specifications.pdf

In GEE you should use the following to apply the Sentinel-2 L2A scaling factor:

```
var image = image.divide(10000)
```

This will apply the scaling factor to all the image bands. Probably you need to create a function and map it over an image collection.

```
var collection = collection.map(
  function(image){return image.divide(10000));
```

Just a simple note: remember that reflectante could be greater than 1 due tu additional luminance or specular effects. This issue was also mentioned in the [sentinel-hub](https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/t/l2a-images-to-range-0-to-1/2505) forum.